# How to script to read user input, then run in background itself even closing terminal in TCSH?

Tags: shell, csh, tcsh

I am looking for a strategy suggestion.
I am very new to Linux shell scripting. Just learning tcsh not more than a month.
I need a script to automatically detects when is the result files are done copied back from a remote server to a folder in a remote machine, then start scp the files back to my workstation. 
I do not know in advance when the job will finish run, so the folder could have no result files for a long while. I also do not know when will the last result file done copied back from remote server to the folder (and thus can start the scp).

I had tried crontab. Work fine when I guess correctly, most of the time just disappointing.
So I tried to write a script myself and I have it now. I intend to produce a script that serves me and my colleagues too.
To use the script, the user first need to login to the remote machine manually. Then only execute the script at remote machine. The script first asks for user to input their local machine name and directory where they wish to save the result files. 
Then the script will just looping to test when is the total number of files change. When it detected that, which means the first result file is starting to be copied back from the remote server, then it loops again to detect when is the total files size in the folder stop changing, which means last result file is finished copied to the folder. After that it executes scp to send all the result files to the user workstation, at the initially specified directory.

Script works fine but I wish to make the script able to run in background and still running by itself even if the user logout from the remote machine and close the terminal. And also I wish to let the user just type in a simple command in terminal to start the script, something like a simple

```
./script.tcsh
```

I tried to run the script by command

```
./script.tcsh &
```

but fails, because background process unable to accept user input.

Google and found something called disown, but the command is not found. Apparently the remote machine and my machine does not support this command.

Tried to modify the script to first accept the user input, then attempt to use

```
cat > temp_script.tcsh << EOF 
   {rest of my script}
EOF
```

and then a line of

```
./temp_script.tcsh &
```

to try to create another script file and use the first script to initiate the second script in background. Also fail, because cat does not treat $variable as a literal text, it replaces it with values. I have a foreach i(1 2) loop, and the cat command just keep reporting error (missing value of variable i, which is just a counter in foreach loop syntax).

I am out of idea at the moment.
Can anyone enlighten me with some strategy that I can try myself?
The goal is to use only 1 script file, and prompt user for 2 inputs (machine name and directory to save), then no more interaction with user or waiting, and able to run even closing the terminal.

Note: I do not need password to login to remote machine and back.

Comment: Perhaps "nohup"? This sort of feels more like a question suited for Super User (https://superuser.com/) or similar.

Comment: jdv, do you mean instead of starting the script at remote machine with command:


./script.tcsh

I can use the command instead:

nohup ./script.tcsh

am I correct?

Comment: And the script needs to ask for two user input at terminal at the beginning.
Will nohup still allow that?

Comment: Anyway I will ask the same question again in Superuser as suggested.

Comment: Do yourself a favour, and learn to do your scripting in a shell language suited to that. This problem is very simple to solve in Bourne Shell (and its modern derivatives like BASH.) See http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt for some reasons why.

Comment: Hey just to update here, my problem solved. 
using `cat > temp_script.tcsh << "EOF"` and then let the `temp_script.tcsh &` run in background.